# Azure Data Factory DataFlow Error: Key partitioning does not allow computed columns

Tags: azure-data-factory, partitioning, delta-lake

[image: Parameters]

[image: Source Settings]

[image: Optimize]

We have a generic dataflow that works for many tables, the schema is detected at runtime.
We are trying to add a Partition Column for the Ingestion or Sink portion of the delta.

We are getting error:
Azure Data Factory DataFlow Error: Key partitioning does not allow computed columns
Job failed due to reason: at Source 'Ingestion'(Line 7/Col 0): Key partitioning does not allow computed columns

Can we pass the partition column as a parameter to a generic dataflow?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we pass the partition column as a parameter to a generic dataflow?

I tried your scenario and got similar error.

[image]

> There is a limitation of key partition method is **we cannot apply any calculation to the partition column while declaring it.** Instead, this must be created in advanced, either using derived column or read in from source.

To resolve this, you can try following steps -

- First, I created a pipeline parameter with datatype string and gave column name as value.
  [image]
- Click on Dataflow >> Go to Parameter >> In value of parameter select Pipeline expression >> and pass the above created parameter.
  [image]

**OUTPUT:**

It is taking it as partition key column and partitioning data accordingly.
[image]

**Reference** : [How To Use Data Flow Partitions To Optimize Spark Performance In Data Factor](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-data-flow-partitions-to-optimize-spark-performance-in-data-factory/)